# Report Designer Parameter

Tags: report, acumatica, designer

i filter my report with <"BAccount.AcctCD">
[enter image description here]
but i the main report data is from <"LegalGeneralLedgerParameters"> which contains only  <"ReferenceID">
its the same as  <"BAccount.BAccountID">
so my question is can i filter with one field and i get in return i get another one ?
thank you for your cooperation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhu7S.png

Comment: I think I understand what you need but it's not very clear in your question if you are building a new report and why your filter uses a different DAC than the one used for the data. Can you edit you question with more detail? You can add images of the query/tables and filter definitions in your report.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTQOS.png)

this is the filter i need but i don't have a drop list like the above and this is the parametre that i add
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAcKG.png)